# The best way to associate an user with an entity in Apps Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, nosql, datastore

This may be a silly question but i'm totally new to Apps Engine and NoSQL's logic so i'm asking for a suggestion.

I suppose there is an optimal and well-known way to associate an user with an entity in the datastore and i would like to know how to do that, maybe with a guide or a brief example.

I have an user that can subscribe to a Node. I need to know the optimal way to associate these two entities, the best way to check if an user has subscribed to a node and the list of nodes an user has subscribed to.

Thank you in advance^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use python:

```py
class Node(db.Model):
  user = db.UserProperty()

user = users.get_current_user()
qry = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Node WHERE user = :1", user)
```

For the rest see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries)

Comment: This didn't answer the original question in any ways. How do we associate a Node to a User? By having a user_id property in the Node entity, as in usual relational db scenario? I think that's the real question. Also, the node given by the original example is not any boolean value.

Comment: @viz you right and after 7 years I don't know what happened. Probably a misunderstand of the question.

Comment: yeah haha that's fine, I understand. I was actually looking for an answer for this. the answer I found for future audience would be to look into this article for establishing one to many relationship in GAE: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling